# OAuth2 grant for interacting between my Angular app and my REST API?

Tags: angularjs, symfony, oauth, oauth-2.0

Help me pick the right OAuth2 grant type for my Angular App and my REST API?

UX-wise I want just one login form on my front-end, that would ask for username/pass(no dialog asking for permissions). I think the "Resource Owner(Password) Grant" is the most appropriate for me(since I control front&backend), but I'm not sure how should I handle access token refresh.

Correct me if I wrong about the flow:

- When user submits credentials through login form, `access token` is returned.
- I can store this token in `LocalStorage` to make subsequent Ajax requests with it.
- As I understand `access tokens` should be short-lived. And should be updated with `Refresh token`. Should the `refresh token` be returned with the `access token` after initial login and also stored on the client? If not what is the alternative?

  - Should there be any session maintained on the server to invoke `access token` refresh? or I should make calls from front-end to refresh the `access token` when it is about to expire. But then I need a `refresh token` on the front-end, right?

As you see there is a mess in my head about `refresh token`. Would be great to have some clarification or suggestion for another grant implementation.

---

Backend technology I guess is irrelevant here, but just in case it's Symfony2 with FOSOAuthServerBundle.

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling the TOKEN endpoint (for every grant_type possible) on a OAuth Server, you get an access_token but other information as well (I think there are all here):

```
{
  access_token: // your short-lived token
  expires_in: // number of seconds before the access_token is invalid
  token_type: // the type of the access_token
  scope: // scopes of the access_token
  refresh_token: // long-lived token to get a new access_token
}
```

You need, in my opinion, all these information (maybe the scope is unused, but all others will be used later). You have to store the access_token to ba able to make API calls. After  seconds, your access_token will not work anymore. You will need to get a new one. You can either ask the user to log in AGAIN or use the refresh_token.

You will have to call the OAuth Server on the TOKEN endpoint but with a grant_type: refresh_token. You will have to provide the refresh_token from the first request (among other information) and in return you will have the same response as above. In fact, I think you will have to do that every time an access_token is expired. In my opinion, the server side does not know anything about sessions or connected users. It knows about valid and invalid access_token.

This is OAuth. If you don't want to have to refresh everytime, you can make a long-lived access_token (by setting the expires_in), I think this is the only solution that makes sens in an OAuth context.

Do you need some clarification about OAuth in general?

Comment: One thing I'm not clear about, is when to refresh the `access_token`. Let's say `access_token` has expired. User is making request, server returns access denied. `Refresh_token` is sent to `/token` endpoint to get a new `access_token`. `Access_token` is returned, and now the original request is repeated again with the new `access_token`. That's 3 requests vs. 1. Is there a better strategy to refresh the token?

Comment: You could save one request by trying to know if the access_token has expired BEFORE sending the user's request. To do that, when retrieving the access_token the first time, you could save a expires_at var with a concrete timestamp. Then you just have to compare the current timestimp with expires_at. This way you know if you have to refresh the access_token before any request is made!
This is ok for you?